# PHP - How would i go about doing a loop until condition is true, WITHOUT CRASHING

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to do a while loop to keep checking to see if the strings match, if the strings match than it will make the variable true, if not it will give the loop a little break. How can i go about doing this so it doesn't crash my whole server.

```
     do {
        $Blurb =json_decode($RBLXClass->getBlurb($RBLXClass->GetUserID($LT->RobloxAccount))); 
        if (preg_match('/\b'.$GETVerifyToken.'\b/', $Blurb->data->blurb)) {
            $foundToken = true;
        } else {
            sleep(2);
        }
    } while ($foundToken == false);
```

Comment: Just a small tip, if you move the `$Blurb =` line outside the loop, you'll only be doing that one, that might help a little in terms of speed. You can either use `flush` (prob not best way), or if this is a webpage, use ajax to load the results of this in.

Comment: @RichBradshaw well i kind of need that inside the loop because i need it to keep checking for an updated string

Comment: Is this running from a web page? Or a cron/batch job

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is running from a webpage.

Comment: What do you mean by crash your server? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @NicholasRiceSocialville I don't think you do need it, as nothing in the `do {} while` changes it - isn't the value of $Blurb the same at the start of each loop? If so, that might be enough to make it fast.

Comment: @RichBradshaw when it uses the function getBlurb, it returns a string which could be updated or could stay the same.

Comment: Does it crash with `max_execution_time` exceeded

Comment: @ChipDean It allocates all the memory on my server and quite literally kills it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No it does not, it just takes up all the memory in the matter of seconds and just crashes the server, and won't load until i reset it from my provider's dashboard.

Comment: Does not look like this code would do that, so the problem must be in the funtion you are calling

Comment: @RiggsFolly well the functions gets from a nodejs server that is running.

Comment: thoughts: Does it crash the server if you comment out the sleep? i.e. is there some memory allocation / free bug elsewhere in the routine that is called from this code?